# How to set rate limit on my outgoing requests on my own local system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, rate-limiting

Is it possible to set a rate limit in all requests which are outgoing from my own local system? I want my server not to be banned or blocked by other servers.

I searched for a forward proxy with *NGINX* but didn't find an official way to do that.

Maybe there is a way with `ufw` or `iptables` or anything?

Comment: SO is for programming problems. Please try asking at superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: SO specifically has an [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx?tab=Newest) tag

Comment: @AnthumChris The fact SO has a tag does not mean it is on-topic, or that all questions about that are on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can limit it on NGINX server. You can configure NGINX as a proxy for all your outbound requests to external services and use module ngx_http_limit_req_module. Example of configuration and main idea, described in this article: https://www.monterail.com/blog/2011/outbound-api-rate-limits-the-nginx-way.

link to NGINX module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html